# laravel before filter not triggered by browser back button

Tags: authentication, laravel, browser-cache, back

I am using laravel for my web application.

Login route is handled by two methods
LOGIN::GET -> Displays the page to get the login credentials using a form.
LOGIN::POST -> Gets the data posted, authenticates and redirects to admin's home page if the credentials are valid.

Logout just clears the session and redirects to Login::Get.

Admin route has the before filter that performs authentication. If user is logged in then admin's home page is displayed.

Issues pops up when I do the following steps,
Step 1: Visit login page, enter credentials and submit.
Step 2: Credentials are validated and I am shown the admin's home page.
Step 3: I happily logout of the application and see the login page.
Step 4: Press back button. Problem starts, I am seeing the admin's home page.

But after I logout, if I enter the admin's home page URL and enter, I am correctly redirected to login page. This happens only with browser back button.

If this is a browser cache issue how do I control it? How do I get to trigger the before filter even when I press back button?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah pretty sure it is just the browser cache. When you logout do you redirect to the login page or are you just returning the login page? Always redirect, might fix your issue as when you press back you would get the the login action which would be invalid as you aren't logged in and then go to the login action. If you pressed back twice you might still get this issue but that would be very rare.

Comment: I redirect to login page, but still problem occurs.
What I have done now is, I have created a after filter for all the secure web pages and added the meta headers(cache-control, pragme and expires) to avoid caching. The problem doesn't occur now but still I want to know if there is anyother fool proof method to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

the same problem with codeigniter. Need to add the header cache-control.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26560336/434790

I tried to solve this issue with a bit of javascript code in my base template just before  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var isAuth = "<?php echo Auth::check(); ?>";

        if (location.href === 'http://local.myapp.in/login/')
        {
            if (isAuth) location.href('/home');
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isAuth) location.href('/login');
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the above code, replace http://local.myapp.in/login/ with your login page URL. So each time a page is loaded, this code gets executed. If the user is trying to access any restricted page without loggedin, then he will be redirected to login page. And if a user is trying to access login page when logged in, browser will be redirected to home page.

Since, it is js code, even if the page is loaded from browser cache this piece of code runs.